# Is $\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{(-2)^n+n^2}{n \cdot 2^n}$ convergent or divergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to figure out whether this series is convergent or divergent.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-2)^n+n^2}{n\cdot2^n}$$

The sequence is a convergent zero sequence and at some point it's seems to be alternating, but it is not the series for using Leibniz' criterion.
If I cancel $2^{n}$ I would get a kind of alternating zero sequence. for which Leibniz is applicable, but I am not sure whether is is right.
Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-2)^n+n^2}{n\cdot2^n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}$$

Think about the convergence of these two terms.

Comment: Well, thank you stonebrakermatt!
They are both convergent!

Comment: In addition: the value of the series is $-\ln{2}+2$

Comment: This series conditinally convergent right?